# Best Linux distribution for PC with low specifications

Tags: linux

I have a PC with only

- 2GB DDR2 RAM
- Intel Core 2 Duo Processor
- 256GB Intel Integrated Graphics
  I want to use a stable Linux distribution that can run smooth in my PC.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you are new to linux. Speaking of light-weight distributions, there are a lot of them. I fear no one can suggest you nothing unless you mention about your usage too. Anyway you can find some good ones here: https://fossbytes.com/best-lightweight-linux-distros/ Make sure you do your research before you try them.

Comment: Welcome Aayush.  Please edit your question to describe how you define "best".  Thanks!